Conditional and unconditional mean in GARCH(1,1) model
Say I have a stationary time series and want to fit a GARCH(1,1) model. Does this mean that the conditional mean, which is used in GARCH, would always be the same as the unconditional mean of the whole time series?

No. A stationary time series can have time-varying conditional mean (as e.g. in ARMA where the AR part is stationary) and time-varying conditional variance (as e.g. in GARCH where the conditional variance is stationary). For example, the following ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1) is a stationary process:
\begin{aligned}
x_t &= \mu_t + u_t, \\
\mu_t &= 0.1 + 0.5 x_{t-1} + 0.2 u_{t-1}  \quad \text{(ARMA)}, \\
u_t &= \sigma_t \varepsilon_t, \\
\sigma_t^2 &= \omega + 0.1 u_{t-1}^2 + 0.85 \sigma_{t-1}^2  \quad \text{(GARCH)}, \\
\varepsilon_t &\sim i.i.D(0,1),
\end{aligned}
where $D$ is some probability distribution with zero mean and unit variance.
If we replaced $0.5 x_{t-1}$ with $x_{t-1}$, we would get nonstationarity due to the conditional mean.
If we replaced $0.85 \sigma_{t-1}^2$ with $0.9 \sigma_{t-1}^2$, we would get nonstationarity due to the conditional variance.

What if the mean process is constant mean? Basically ARMA(0,0).

So instead of the first two lines we have something like $r_t=\mu+\sigma_t\epsilon_t$.

@statwoman, that is also a valid stationary process.

In this case can $\mu\neq \sum r_t/n$ still hold?

@statwoman, yes. Now, you are comparing the theoretical parameter $\mu$ with a sample quantity (sample mean $\bar r$). But it can even be true for $\hat\mu$ in place of $\mu$, as the maximum likelihood estimator of the constant will be a weighted mean, not a simple mean, because we use lower weights for high-cond.-variance observations and higher weights for low-cond.-variance observations.
